# On Send in Microsoft Outlook for Windows Client

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am wondering if Microsoft finally allowed for a developers to use the OnSend functionality in the Windows Outlook Client. I know when it came out a while back that was not possible because of permission / security settings. I am in need of this function and want to avoid going back to an old vsto way. Can some one provide some info if its possible now and also point me to some docs.

Answer (score 0):

It is allowed now, but you won't be able to have an addin that requests it in the store.

Comment: i don't care about the store as it is an internal app so i can host it on a private web server only accessible to target audience